# Redeclare destructured variables in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to use destructuring in Typescript GraphQL. A lot of the API functions use `data` as the first level key. How can I do the below without a Typescript/TSLint error. Changing to `var` will result in it wanting to be `let`, which `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable` & `block-scoped used before its declaration`. `const` of course is an error. Removing the 2nd `let` will not allow me to destructure the 2nd `data`.

```
let {data}:OverlayEventDetail = await modal.onDidDismiss();
if (data.save) {
  if (shop) {
    //update
  } else {
    const input: CreateShopInput = {
      name: typeof data.name === 'string' && data.name.length > 0 ? data.name : null,
      keywords: []
    };
    let {data}:{data:CreateBlahMutation} = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.createShop, {input}));
  }
}
```

My current solution is with both `const {data}` and `// @ts-ignore` on the `name` line.

Comment: Are the variables of the same type ?

Comment: If they are of the same type you don't need to declare the variable, you can destructure into existing variables: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBA9hC8EG8IBMCGZUC4IEYIF8AoUSJNDAuCaAbkIAoFzV8qoBKIA

Comment: No, the functions return `any` but I can type the `data`s differently ( `{data}:OverlayEventDetail` + `{data}:{data:CreateBlahMutation}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can't reuse the name, you can still destructure while assigning to a different variable:

```js
let {data: apiData}: {data:CreateBlahMutation} = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.createShop, {input}));
```

This will assign the `data` property of `await API.graphql(...)` to the variable `apiData`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the assignment without declaring the variable. You will need to add parentheses around the statement though:

`({data} = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.createShop, {input})));`

Comment: This works except for adding a type: `({data}:{data:CreateShopMutation} = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.createShop, {input})));` =>  `'CreateShopMutation' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: If you really need to type your function, you can do it like so:
`({data} = (await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.createShop, {input}))) as {data:CreateShopMutation});`

Comment: Definitely need to type the function...GQL has some pretty epic typing!! Sadly this is now assigning `data:any` :(